# display element multiple times

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to display a little box multiple times with jquery. I goal is something like a for loop

```
<span class="box_counter"></span>


 .box_counter {   
   float: left;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   margin: 40px 0px 0px 250px;     
   background-color: black;
 }
```

So like (pseudo code)

```
for (index != total)
  push.box_counter
  index++
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/WUYfW/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply clone the element, and add the copy after it in the DOM [***JSFIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/WUYfW/3/)

```
$(function() {
    var total = 20;

    for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
        $boxCntr = $(".box_counter").first().clone(true);
        $(".box_counter").last().after($boxCntr);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the elements in the loop. Example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $(document.body).append($('<span>').addClass('box_counter'));
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WUYfW/2/